# REST Service - SSL Implementation (HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden)

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

In order to secure my Rest Services, I have enabled SSL in IIS and Created a Self-Signed Certificate and assigned it to the HTTPS binding in IIS. I exported the same as pfx file and added the same in IE also but when I try to access the Services, I get the following error on Windows 7, Enterprise edition

HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.

And on Windows Server 2003, this is

HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

I am not sure what shall I do except adding the certificate in IE under “Personal” and “Trusted Root Certification Authorities”? Could you please suggest me some step, in order to make this work.

Note: I have tried with “Self-Signed Certificates” as well as with Certificates generated from Microsoft “Certificate Services” also.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is used to verify the identity of the server, not the identity of the client. The error suggests (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199215, "This is used for authenticating you as a valid user of the resource. ") the server wants to identify the client. Which of the two are you trying to do?

Edit: SSL requires the public part of the SSL certificate to be available to the client. Adding it to the trusted root certificates seems to me to be the only way to make the public part of a self-signed certificate available to the browser.